# GPG passphrase is not provided during Key Generation and is not working as expected

Tags: gpg

I have created a gpg Key without providing any passphrase. But while generating Digital Signature file I am passing some extra character with --passphrase on the command line. Still I am able to generate the file which is not a valid scenario.

** gpg --output File1.txt.sig --passphrase "abcdef" --default-key (Private_key_name) --detach-sig File1.txt **

In this case passphrase in the command line is not correct. It should be blank. But still I see signature file getting created.
Could anyone help me in knowing the error here!!!